# How to get total number of rows in a executed select statement?

Tags: sql, join, count, sql-server-2012

How can I out how many rows I obtained after execution?

My query is:

```
SELECT a.Emp,b.orders 
from table as a inner join table1 b 
on a.ID = B.ID
```

How do I find the number of rows returned in the above join?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either have to use  `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` with the same condition or add a column with the row-count via [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
SELECT a.Emp,b.orders, RN = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY a.Emp,b.orders) 
FROM table as a inner join table1 b on a.ID=B.ID
```

...or use [`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx?ppud=4) after the select.

Instead of `ROW_NUMBER` it's easier to use `COUNT(*) OVER ( Order By ...)` where each row contains the same total-count whereas `ROW_NUMBER` would return a sequential number where only the last record(acc. to the `ORDER BY`) would have the total-count.

So what Aaron has already meantioned [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21416344/284240).

Comment: Well, the `ROW_NUMBER()` function will be applied in that order, but the result isn't guaranteed to be returned in that order without a matching `ORDER BY` on the outer query, and especially if there is a *different* `ORDER BY`. How do they find the largest `ROW_NUMBER()` value?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: You're right, `COUNT(*)OVER` is much easier(edited).

Answer (score 6):

```
-- statement here
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

You can also get it on every row of the statement, but of course this is a little more expensive, e.g.

```
SELECT x, y, z, COUNT(*) OVER() FROM ...
```