# How to return the # of Rows in a SQL query with groupby and aggregate functions as a single number?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT release_year
FROM films
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(title) > 200;
```

which returns the years in which the total number of films released is greater than 200.

The result prints a list of years that satisfy the criteria. 13 years do.

How do I print out just the number 13 instead?

I've tried the top answer in this solution: 
[How to get total number of rows in a executed select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416291/how-to-get-total-number-of-rows-in-a-executed-select-statement)

The @@ROWCOUNT didn't work for me (I'm using PostgreS, maybe that's the issue)
And when I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() 
FROM films
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(title) > 200;
```

I got a single column, `count`, with 13 rows of `13` printed.

How do I just get the single number of the row count of the 1st query, `13`, printed once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use sub-query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT release_year
    FROM films
    GROUP BY release_year
    HAVING COUNT(title) > 200
) AS tbl;
```